# Palabras del animal: puerco, cochi, cerdo

Tags: méxico, sinónimos, animales

Hay varias palabras que he encontrado para referirse a un animal, pero no entiendo cuándo se usa cada una.

¿Cómo se distinguen los significados de: **puerco, cochi y cerdo**?

Pido respuestas que pertenezcan al español de México, por favor.

Comment: +cochino, marrano, cuino, lechón (puerco bebé), etc.

Comment: Por cierto, *cochi*, no me parece tan común. *Cochino* sí lo es.

Comment: chancho, chanchito...sudamerica

Comment: @c.p., usan estas palabras en Mexico?

Comment: @Joe Así es. Aunque *cuino* es onomatopéyico. Pero he conocido gente que sí lo dice (lenguaje informal).

Comment: El término cochi sí se usa mucho en Sinaloa y regiones aledañas. Es simplemente una abreviación de cochino.

Answer (score 10):

En español, «cerdo» es el nombre común más formal para designar a *Sus scrofa domestica* en un ambiente formal. También se puede emplear sinónimos más coloquiales como puerco, cochino, marrano. guarro y gorrino, pero son más usados cuando la frase es despectiva hacia el animal, y sobre todo si es un insulto hacía una persona, aludiendo a su suciedad, grosería o ruindad.

Son todos casi perfectos sinónimos. El sentido exacto, cuando se usan como insulto, lo proporciona sólo el contexto o la frase, aunque su origen sí que es diverso.
«Puerco» debería ser el nombre común formal, ya que deriva del latín *porcus* y a su vez del indoeuropeo, lo mismo que *pork* en inglés.

«Cerdo» hace alusión al pelo grueso y duro del animal (cerdas, del latín vulgar `cirra` que significa «mechón«).

«Guarro» y «gorrino» derivan de las onomatopeyas de lo gruñidos de los cerdos. 
Si se refiere al animal, «gorrino» tiene realmente el significado de lechón (cerdo  joven), así como el cerdo macho adulto es un «verraco» (del latín *verres*). Creo que «verraco» es también un insulto en Cuba, pero al menos en España se usa en personas en alusión a su fuerza, brutalidad u obsesión sexual, pero no por su falta de higiene.

«Cochino» quizás es un diminutivo del francés *cochon* o tal vez provenga del termino *chochini* que usaban los mexicas para los cerdos porque hacían ruidos como los ronquidos. En cualquier caso, si tuvo un origen americano, desde hace muchos siglos forma parte del vocabulario usual en España.

Marrano viene del árabe andalusí «maharram»  que significaba «cosa prohibida» y pasó al romance como insulto a los judíos conversos al cristianismo en apariencia, y cuya secreta religión les prohibía comer carne de cerdo. De ahí pasó a significar únicamente cerdo, incluso sin sentido peyorativo.

Por último, hay que aclarar el término «cerdo», y sobre todo sus sinónimos coloquiales, son palabras casi tabú en escritos formales, donde se usa y abusa el adjetivo «porcino» para evitar usar un nombre que se suele usar como insulto. A veces hay que leer docenas de veces «ganado porcino» antes de que autor se atreva a nombrar a «los cerdos» por su nombre.

***Adenda***

Me olvidaba de «chancho» que comenta Emilio Gort, que es otro sinónimo común, no sólo de América, aunque ciertamente en España se usa muy poco, y no creo que sea muy común tampoco en México, aunque seguramente no es desconocida para la mayoría de los hispanohablantes. Su origen parece ser que era «sancho»  en la Mancha y Aragón (España), pero no hay acuerdo si el término tenía  relación directa con el nombre propio «Sancho», muy común en España durante la Edad Media por influencia Navarra. Puede que este «otro» significado de «sancho» tuviera que ver con la elección del nombre para el vulgar y tosco escudero de Don Quijote de la Mancha, en cuyo caso no sólo su apellido «Panza» tenía un sentido  humorístico.

El sinónimo que jamás he escuchado es «cuino» pero tampoco es una palabra exclusivamente americana, ya que proviene de Asturias (norte de España). Otro que tampoco escucho nunca, pero viene en el diccionario, es «gocho», pero por avatares de la historia, actualmente parece ser un gentilicio de los andinos venezolanos y relacionado con esto, también significa animal o persona al que le falta una oreja.

Comment: ¿De cual parte del mundo viene esta respuesta?

Comment: @Joe De España, pero no creo que sea relevante en este caso. He estado trabajando con el ganado porcino  junto a algunos  colegas mexicanos durante años y siempre nos entendíamos perfectamente.

Comment: Gracias, pero que las palabras que usa Ud. estan entendidos bien por mexicanos no implica que aquellos mexicanos les usen las mismas palabras.  (Lo que trato que decir en mi lengua maternal: That the words you use are understood by Mexicans does not entail that they would use the same words themselves.)

Comment: @Joe No solo me entendían, ellos también hablaban (y bastante) y yo también les comprendía perfectamente `;)`. Si además algunos mexicanos usan entre ellos alguna palabra del náhuatl, el maya, el otomí, el mixteco o  el purépecha, o algún otros barbarismo o localismo que no aparece el diccionario, lo desconozco, pero en cualquier caso sería discutible encuadrarlo en el idioma español.

Comment: +1 por el dato de la etimología de *marrano*. @Joe lo que dice esta respuesta se entendería cualquier mexicano, estoy seguro. Quizá *guarro* se identificaría en primera instancia como 'hombre de malos modales', pero dado un contexto apropiado, como *cerdo*.

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta de Fran es muy valiosa, pero me parece que lo que tu necesitas es saber cuando usar cual palabra.

En el **español de México**, cuando hablas de comida, las palabras "cochi" y "cochino" casi no se usan porque son un poco más desagradables, "puerco" se usa a veces, pero es más común y aceptado usar "cerdo", por ejemplo "carne de cerdo", "costilla de cerdo", etc.

Pero tu pregunta fue sobre el animal; cuando te refieres al animal vivo, puedes usar cualquiera de esas tres palabras de manera intercambiable, en diferentes regiones se usa diferente palabra con más frecuencia, "cochi" es común en la región noroeste del país, es simplemente una abreviación de "cochino", pero las palabras "puerco" y "cerdo" se entienden bien en todo México y son más usadas, **no hay diferencia textual cuando te refieres al animal**.
Adicionalmente puedo asegurar, que en México es más común usar las palabras "cerdo" y "puerco" sin rodeos, contrario a lo que @Fran menciona en el 7<sup>o</sup> párrafo de su respuesta. El uso formal al estilo que Fran describió ("ganado porcino") es usual siempre en documentación por supuesto. Pero cuando alguien se siente incómodo usando esas palabras, simplemente dirá "cerdito" o "puerquito"; **en México, amenizar el discurso oral usando diminutivos es más común** que usar términos formales.

Sin embargo, cuando se usa como adjetivo calificativo para insultar a una persona (en estilo coloquial), sí existen diferencias subtextuales sutiles y otras no tan sutiles (dependiendo del contexto), pero esa no fue tu pregunta.

Espero que eso aclare tu duda.

Comment: El párrafo 7º de mi respuesta no contradice  que «cerdo» sea de uso común. De hecho, defiendo su uso al mencionar el «abuso» de sustituirla por un eufemismo. Pero como toda palabra utilizable como insulto («eres un cerdo») a veces tiende a evitarse cuando tendría su sentido propio y cabal. Que una palabra sea tabú no implica en absoluto que esté en desuso.  Por ejemplo «aborto»  es una palabra común, pero eso no es impedimento para que muchas veces se sustituya por  «interrupción del embarazo» o eufemismos similares para suavizar sus connotaciones negativas.